# convert string to DateTime in linq query with where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I am try to get user list using EF. and I have one filed in the table it's return date as a string data type. Now I'm compare this return date to Today's date then I'm getting error.so any one idea how can do that convert string to datetime in C#.

Here's the query:

```
var res = db.users
  .Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a.returndate) > DateTime.Now)
  .ToList(); // but here not getting list
```

So it's possible in EF string to DateTime conversion. If  anyone has an idea please let me know.

Comment: What is the value of `a.returndate`?

Comment: DD-MM-YYYY this format it's store

Comment: shouldn't it be DD-MM-YYYY instead of DD-MM-YYY?

Comment: "then I'm getting error" - what error? And do you *have* to use a text representation in the database to start with? If you could change the database to use a more sensible field type, *all* code dealing with it is likely to get better...

Answer (score 13):

You can not use `Convert.ToDatetime` method in `LINQ to Entities`, so first get data from db then use method on list

```
var res = db.users.ToList().Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.returndate,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

**NOTE:** If you can change your `columns data type` to `DateTime` type then you can **compare them** in `LINQ To Entities`, otherwise you should do as above

Comment: with your solution i'm getting like this error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'.

Comment: fetching the whole table to filter the data within the application is bad practice

Comment: @fubo yer you are right, if this table contains very big data

Comment: so guys what is the best wave for that issue to fix?

Comment: if your users table not contains large data, then using this will not cause performance problem

Comment: Vishals answer not working I think, because you can not acces lists object from outside

Comment: @coderwill the best way to fix this issue is to have the correct data type in the database column. The next best way would be to use the date as a string in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), so you can at least compare the text representation without conversion.

Comment: As @Dirk said best way is store data in db as Datetime, then you can compare in LINQ to Entities without converting

Comment: yes but now time i require as a string that's why i am taking string next time will be care it

Comment: @Ikram Turgunbaev  this user table is store lot's of data so i am go for your wave query it's very slow working so any other way for that?

Comment: @coderwill it seems there is no other way until you change data type of your column in db

Comment: ok thanks guys for the helping and give me more suggestion on this issue.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev yes your wave it's 100% correct but in my table lot's of data that time it's perfomance law so i am not used.

Answer (score 4):

As per your comments to question you need to do

```
var res = db.users.ToList().Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.returndate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.Now);
```

In your case `Convert.ToDateTime(string str)` is not working as passed `DateTime` format is different from your System's format.

BTW,

> ....EF string to DateTime conversion.

Never ever store DateTime strings in database. Databases have corresponding DateTime types where you can store information as DateTime itself. That way when bringing values you don't have to repeat the code.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. i m getting this error.

Comment: Thanks guys for noticing.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the `ToList()` call forces the SQL to execute and the `Where()` is performed in code.

Comment: Yes. That's Immediate Query Execution (opposite of Deferred Query Execution which LINQ does). OP is also doing `ToList()` in his question. Is there a question in this?

Answer (score 0):

With current schema you can only get list of all objects and then filter it.

Linq to Entities constructs SQL query which is executed when enumeration is done.

So just get full list, then filter it. Or database schema changing is strongly recommended.

**UPDATE**

```
var res = db.users.ToList().Where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.returndate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.Now);
```

But full table is loaded before filtration. So u need to change your field type to datetime. Then u can use simple comparison inside `Where`.

@NikhilAgrawal also updated his answer in a right way. )

Comment: can you please give me hint how can do that

Comment: yes this wave it's correct but in my table lot's of data is store so that time this query it's work very slow so any other solution??

Comment: I mentioned - change field type to datetime, the only way.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
var res = db.users.where(a => DateTime.ParseExact(a.returndate,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.now).ToList();
```

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` will not be translated into a sql statement

Answer (score -1):

You can access in a list then appy filter like below-

var users=db.users.ToList();

var res=users.Where(a=>Convert.ToDateTime(a.returndate)>DateTime.Now).ToList();

Comment: Bad advice: this pulls the entire table into memory.